# Does pattern in random seed for Pseudo random functions cause bias

Tags: random-generation

I am using random forest in R, and for different test sets I'm using patterned seeds in the sample function. For one test set I use 1234, for the next 2345, the next 3456. I suspect it is unlikely, but could this introduce bias of some sort?

Comment: I would be more concerned about trying so few seeds than by having some simple rule to generate them.

Comment: The computer won't even recognize such decimal patterns because the seeds are represented in binary.

Comment: @Galen I should have put an ellipsis, this was just to show you the series.